# Adding a static background to a uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to add a static background to a collectionview because at the moment the background scrolls with the cells and the image looks quite bad.

my code at the moment

```
collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How can we suggest a fix if we can't see what you're already doing. If you're adding the background to the collection view, you should be getting your desired behavior. It sounds like you're adding the background to the collection view cells themselves.

Comment: @0x7fffffff collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to do what you're asking.

1. add the background to the `UICollectionView` as a subview like you're doing now and implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method. Inside that method, set the frame of the background view based on the `contentOffset` of the collection view which will make it appear to be static on the screen. You will just need to set the frame's Y origin to be the `contentOffset.y` and it should work. (If there is a  non-zero `contentInset` you may need to do a bit of additional math to get it right.)
2. add the background to the `superview` of your collection view, underneath the collection view. This is an easier and probably more efficient solution since you don't need to mess with the contentOffset at all since the background will not be in the scroll view itself.

Comment: Ah thanks. I added self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]; in viewdid load and its working now

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that! My answer is a more general case for any `UIScrollView` and what you are using is a nice convenience made specifically for `UICollectionView`. In fact, it is probably what I outlined in method #1 under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your requirement correctly, here's how you can do it:

1) Add your static image as a subview to the parentView.

2) Set the backgroundColor of collectionView to [UIColor clearColor]

3) Add collection view as a subview to the parentView.